# Do pharmaceuticals which increase dopamine and norepinephrine levels in the brain significantly increase histamine levels?

Tags: neurology, medications, adhd, stimulants, dopamine

I imagine any medication that has an effect on catecholamines would in some way increase histamine levels as well, just for the fact that histamine is part of the 'fight or flight' response and seems to go along with catecholamine activation. (I'm not super knowledgeable on neurophysiology, so please excuse my ignorance of its complexities and the extent of different pathways).

Q 1: If an individual has problems with high histamine levels related to frequent stress response activation and subsequent cortisol spikes, would medications such as adderall and other stimulants greatly exacerbate histamine related physiological imbalances? Note: high histamine levels prevail in spite of antihistamine use.

Q 2: If, as I suspect, stimulant medications do have too much of an effect on histamine levels, what alternatives are there for remedying low dopamine levels and poor executive functioning due to depression and ADHD?